# Jest async action creators:TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, redux-async-actions

Kinda newbie to jest here.I am trying to write unit test cases for one of the async action creators in my React project using jest. I keep running into the error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**

Below is my action creator:

```
import {loginService} from "./services";

export function login(email: string, password: string): (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, any>) => void {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(loggingIn(true));
    loginService(email, password).then(
      (response: any) => {
        dispatch(loggingIn(false));
        dispatch(loginAction(response));
      },
      error => {
       //Code
        }
        dispatch(loggingIn(false));
        dispatch(loginError(true, message));
      }
    );
  };
}
```

**./services.js**

```
export const loginService = (username: string, password: string) => {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      //Headers
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({email: username, password: password})
  };
  return fetch(`url`, requestOptions)
    .then(handleResponse, handleError)
    .then((user: any) => {
      //code
      return user;
    });
};
```

Given below is my test:

```
it("login", () => {
    fetchMock
      .postOnce("/users/auth", {
        body: JSON.parse('{"email": "user", "password": "password"}'),
        headers: {"content-type": "application/json"}
      })
      .catch(() => {});
    const loginPayload = {email: "user", password: "password"};
    const expectedSuccessActions = [
      {type: types.LOGGING_IN, payload: true},
      {type: types.LOGIN, loginPayload}
    ];
    const expectedFailureActions = [
      {type: types.LOGGING_IN, payload: true},
      {type: types.LOGIN_ERROR, payload: {val: true, errorMessage: "error"}}
    ];
    const store = mockStore({user: {}});
    const loginService = jest.fn();
    return store.dispatch(LoginActions.login("email", "password")).then(() => {
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedSuccessActions);
    });
  });
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The end result returned by dispatching your `LoginActions.login()` action is `void` (or `undefined`). Not a `Promise`, so not something you can call `.then()` on in your test.

Judging by your test code, you're using `fetch-mock` for your `fetchMock`. You should be able to [wait for that to finish](http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/#api-lifecycleflush) before testing that the store dispatched the correct actions:

```
it("login", async () => {
//          ^^^^^ --> note that you need to make your test async to use await

    store.dispatch(LoginActions.login("email", "password"));
    await fetchMock.flush();

    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedSuccessActions);
});
```

Note that the comments in your code seem to indicate that your `loginService` does some more things before returning from the `.then()` callback. If that takes too long, waiting for the `fetchMock` to finish might not be waiting long enough. In that case, you should consider returning the `Promise` from your `LoginActions.login()` action so that you *can* test it. Whether or not you *should* depends on how much effort it would be to adjust your application to handle that, since you don't want your app to crash with any unhandled promise rejection errors in case the login fails.

Comment: Thank you @rickdenhaan. I tried the your solution. Yet no luck. The error I am getting is inside the action creator itself once I run the test and not inside the test function. The undefined error is given where the loginService function is called.Could there be something I am missing out?

Comment: That would mean `loginService(email, password)` is returning `undefined`, which the code in your question shouldn't. Are you mocking it somewhere?